# PHP dynamic HTML table using SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

### Background

I am using the below code to generate a HTML table based on SQL results.

**Code**

```
  $stid = oci_parse($conn, "

    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
     SELECT   orders.order_no, orders.porder_no, orders.date, order_totals.value
     FROM     orders, order_totals
     WHERE    orders.order_no = order_totals.order_no
     AND      orders.account_no = '" . $_SESSION['session_account'] . "'
     ORDER BY orders.order_no DESC
    )
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 15

  ");
  oci_execute($stid);

  echo "<table class='table'>
        <thread>
        <tr>
        <th>Order No</th>
        <th>Purchase Order No</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        </thread>
        <tbody>";

  while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td><a href="view.php?id=' . $row['0'] . '">' . $row['0'] . '</a></td>';
    echo "<td>" . $row['1'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['2'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['3'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    unset($row);
  }

  echo "</tbody>
        </table>";
```

### Question

Is it possible to make the HTML table generation part in the code more dynamic, so that if I need to add an additional column for example I can just ammend the SQL part in the code?

I had an idea to set the column headings using `AS` in SQL and I can amend the SQL to use `AS` to show the real column headings I want for example

```
SELECT orders.order_no    AS "Order No"
,      orders.porder_no   AS "Purchase Order No"
,      orders.date        AS "Date"
,      order_totals.value AS "Total"
```

but what about the HTML table part, is there some method to just print all columns and rows dynamically, like maybe create a function `printTable` that would handle *any* table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $row var is an array so you can loop over that too. Since you want to treat your first field differently write it out before the loop and start the loop at 1.

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td><a href="view.php?id=' . $row[0] . '">' . $row[0] . '</a></td>';
    for ( $ii = 1; $ii < count($row); $ii++ ) {
        echo "<td>" . $row[$ii] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

I don't know what the unset($row) was for, so I left it out.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to write the column headings from the SQL also?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT * FROM {TABLENAME}
```

Then fetch an array.
You can get data with `$row['{FIELDNAME}']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use double loop:

```
$results = $PDO->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // here is all columns and rows from db query.

echo '<table><tr>';

// loop only first row to get header
foreach ($results[0] as $header => $value) {
   echo "<th>{$header}</th>"
}

echo '</tr>';

// loop all rows
foreach ($results as $row) {
   echo '<tr>';
   // and loop any number of columns
   foreach ($row as $cellName => $cell) {

      // If you have only one special case, than use if statement
      switch ($cellName) {
          case 'order_no':
               echo "<td><a href='http://example.com/getOrder?id={$cell}'>{$cell}</a></td>";
               break;
          default: echo "<td>{$cell}</td>";
      }
   }
   echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```